# Добавление элементов друг за другом

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть некий [скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/v33feyxy/), который должен добавить 3 раза один элемент после последнего `tr#char_block_set`.
Но добавляет почему-то только один. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это поправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала немного исправления ошибок:

1. Не пытайтесь клонированировать элемент с id, на одной странице может быть только 1 элемент с id, поэтому создание нескольких таких элементов может вызвать проблемы.
2. Чтобы убрать элемент со страницы, недостаточно просто стереть его содержимое в html, элемент останется, только пустой. Используйте, например, функцию `detach()`.

---

Теперь до делу:

Суть работы функции `clone()` в том, что при создании с помощью неё элемента в DOM этот элемент будет добавляться только 1 раз, и все манипуляции с клоном будут происходить всегда с одним и тем же элементом. То есть добавление клона 3 раза, это всё равно что 3 раза поставить в конец очереди одного человека, человек всё равно останется один. В доказательство утверждения [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/v33feyxy/1/) на основе данных автора. Клон добавляем 3 раза с разными классами, в итоге получается элемент, имеющий 3 класса, которые он получал по очереди при каждом новом добавлении на страницу.

Поэтому вам нужно делать 3 клона для добавления элемента несколько раз, но при этом вам нужно добавлять клоны в конец таблицы, убирая исходный элемент. Могу вам предложить такой вариант:

Исходную строку всё-таки называем классом, а не id. Для последней строки таблицы определяем `class="last"`. Пишем функцию для клонирования элемента, при этом клонируем исходного клона `char_b_tr` каждый раз заново, если бы вам не нужно было убирать первоначальный элемент, то можно было бы клонировать сам элемент:

```
   function pasteClone() {
        var stroke = char_b_tr.clone().addClass("fsdfsdf" + i);
        $('.last').before(stroke);
        i++;
    }
```

С помощью `detach()` убираем исходный элемент. А далее вызываем функцию клонирования 3 раза.

Вот [итоговый пример](http://jsfiddle.net/v33feyxy/2/).

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой развёрнутный ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Для мультиклонирования, можете добавить такое расширение jQuery

```
$.fn.duplicate = function(count, cloneEvents) {
    var tmp = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        $.merge( tmp, this.clone( cloneEvents ).get() );
    }
    return this.pushStack( tmp );
};
```

Пример использования:

```
$('.char_block_set').duplicate(3).insertAfter('.char_block_set:last');
```