# Как копировать 1 элемент и вставить его несколько раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как скопировать колонку из таблицы и вставить ее к примеру 4 раза? В дальнейшем необходимо будет узнать кол-во строк через `length` и затем копировать элемент столько раз сколько вышло строк в таблице.

```js
var needCols = $('.matrix_b').find('tr:first td').length;
console.log(needCols);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="matrix_b brackets" id="matrix_b">

           <tr>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,1">
            </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,2">
             </td>
             <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b1,3">
             </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,1">
            </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,2">
            </td>
            <td class="str_inp">
              <input type="text" placeholder="b2,3">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: лучше бы такие вещи на React делать: иметь модель таблицы, менять модель, отрисовывать по ней всю таблицу )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант добавления данных в таблицу. Скрипт добавляет 5 колонок, количество добавляемых колонок можно задавать через переменную `count`.

```js
var rows = $('.matrix_b').find('tr');
var cells = rows.eq(0).find('td').length;
var count = 5;

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  cells++;
  rows.each(function(index) {
    var rowCount = index + 1;
    $(this).append('<td class="str_inp">' +
      '<input type="text" placeholder="b' + rowCount + ',' + cells + '">' +
      '</td>');
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="matrix_b brackets" id="matrix_b">

  <tr>
    <td class="str_inp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="b1,1">
    </td>
    <td class="str_inp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="b1,2">
    </td>
    <td class="str_inp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="b1,3">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="str_inp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="b2,1">
    </td>
    <td class="str_inp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="b2,2">
    </td>
    <td class="str_inp">
      <input type="text" placeholder="b2,3">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: ооооо,шикарно. Спасибо т.е как я понимаю добавление можно сделать именно через цикл?

Comment: Ну да, цикл с count, который добавит нужное количество колонок, и цикл-перебор всех строк таблицы с добавлением в каждую строку нужного  контента, если бы контент ячеек был одинаковый, то можно было бы ещё проще сделать: `rows.append('<td></td>');` и во все строки добавляется по ячейке и получается новая колонка

Comment: А если заменить append на clone последней колонки,то в принципе копировать будет столько раз сколько указанно в count?

Comment: По идее мне нужно дописать функцию которая будет копировать нужное кол-во элементов,а вычисление строк и столбцов тут 
[ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/522513/209467)т.е по логике можно впихнуть итог условия в переменную count и тем самым знать необходимое кол-во

Comment: почитайте про `clone()` мой ответ тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373752/ Суть в том, что если вы попытаетесь клонировать ранее добавленный клон, то это приведёт к ошибке, поэтому если нет необходимости использовать именно `clone()`, то лучше его и не использовать

Comment: надо будет почитать,но пока в моем проекте ошибок при добавлении строк и столбцов не замечено)http://serjo96.github.io/matrix/

Comment: Ну как я понял там была проблема в том что копия была элемента с id. у меня только 1 класс весит на строках и не состыковок не должно быть по идее.Да и консоль чиста)и копировать в таком случае можно первый элемент а не последний)