# Как передать количество элементов в переменную и объявить ее в другой функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не совсем понял код который мне дали, нужно что бы и полученное число которое выводится в консоль использовать в качестве переменной, которая находится в цикле увлечения строк.

1.Первая функция сравнивает кол-во строк и столбцов таблиц А - С , В - С и если добавляется или удаляется строчка или столбец в А и В таблицу  то выводится в консоль информация сколько нужно добавить строк и столбцов таблице С.

2. Вторая функция копирует нужное кол-во  строк С таблице.

сами функции

```
function check_matrix () {
  var needRows = $('.matrix_a').find('tr').length;
  var needCols = $('.matrix_b').find('tr:first td').length;

  var hasRows = $('.matrix_c').find('tr').length;
  var hasCols = $('.matrix_c').find('tr:first td').length;

  var message = "Info:\n";

  if (needRows > hasRows)
    message += "\n- add " + (needRows - hasRows) + " row[s]" ;
  else if (needRows < hasRows)
    message += "\n- remove " + (hasRows - needRows) + " row[s]";
  else
    message += "\n- rows match";

  message += "\n";

  if (needCols > hasCols)
    message += "\n- add " + (needCols - hasCols) + " column[s]" ;
  else if (needCols < hasCols)
    message += "\n- remove " + (hasCols - needCols) + " column[s]";
  else
    message += "\n- columns match";


function addElement(){
  var rows = $('.matrix_c').find('tr:last');
  var cells = rows.eq(0).find('td').length;
  var count = 5;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    count++;
    rows.each(function(index) {
      var rowCount = index + 1;
      $(this).clone().appendTo('.matrix_c')
    });
  };
}
  console.log(message);

}
```

Ссылка на [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZGjoM) функция check_matrix () срабатывает при нажатии кнопки " умножить матрицы ".

Comment: Так может стоит спросить  у того, кто "дал" вам код?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, код из второй функции писал я, но там этот код ещё не был функцией, которую нужно вызывать :) первую функцию помогали делать в другом вопросе тут

Comment: @MasterAlex да,сидел пол дня ломал голову но так к ничему толковому и не пришел)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev - Ну я "дал" код. Давайте у меня спросим. Только я вопроса что-то не вижу.

Comment: @Drop Вам нужно сначала проверить (вставить/удалить) строки в матрице `C`, а потом - столбцы.

Comment: @Igor, так вот же, вопрос "_Не совсем понял код который мне дали,_". А за разъяснениями ТС должен был обратиться к вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check_matrix() {
  var needsRows = +$("#rows").val();//$('.matrix_a').find('tr').length;
  var needsCols = +$("#cols").val();//$('.matrix_b').find('tr:first td').length;

  check_rows(needsRows);
  check_cols(needsCols);
}

function check_rows(needsRows) {
  while ($('.matrix_c').find('tr').length > needsRows) {
    $('.matrix_c').find('tr:last').remove();
  }
  while ($('.matrix_c').find('tr').length < needsRows) {
    $('.matrix_c table').append('<tr></tr>');
  }
}

function check_cols(needsCols) {
  var rows = $('.matrix_c').find('tr');
  for (var iRow = 0; iRow < rows.length; iRow++) {
    while ($(rows[iRow]).find('td').length > needsCols) {
      $(rows[iRow]).find('td:last').remove();
    }
    while ($(rows[iRow]).find('td').length < needsCols) {
      $(rows[iRow]).append('<td><input /></td>');
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnCheck").click(function(){
    check_matrix();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Rows:<input type="text" id="rows" value="5"/>
<br/>
Columns:<input type="text" id="cols" value="3"/>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btnCheck">Check</button>
<br/>
<div class="matrix_c">
  <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Вкладка зависает,возможно цикл не перестает обрабатываться?

Comment: повставляйте вызовов `console.log` и посмотрите в каком цикле происходит зависание

Comment: @Drop Опа, пропустил ++ в `for (var iRow = 0; iRow < rows.length; iRow++) {`.

Comment: Видимо еще где то не хватает прибавления. Снова зависло)

Comment: @Drop вот работающий код

Comment: Не хватало добавления ++?

Comment: Да (13 символов нужно...)

Comment: Кстати а зачем переменную iRow занесли в массив?

Comment: Странно что он да же в codepen ругается на бесконечный цикл на 0 строчке.А в  check_rows случайно цикл не бесконечный?)у него же если я правильно понял нет поиска значений,и он постоянно его перебирает

Comment: Пардон,не заметил комментарий про console.log. Не думал что вообще будет работать при зависании. Итого бесконечный цикл тут `while ($('.matrix_c').find('tr').length < needsRows) {
    $('.matrix_c table').append('<tr></tr>');
    console.log('2 проверка');
  }`
и как всегда я был не внимателен. У меня нет в коде .matrix_c table. .matrix_c класс таблицы)

Comment: @Drop - Поэтому я и включил html верстку в свой код - чтобы Вы могли видеть, как javascript привязан к структуре html.  "зачем переменную iRow занесли в массив" - я использую эту переменную как индекс для доступа к элементам массива.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Наконец то калькулятор закончен. Благо многое узнал благодаря этому калькулятору и вам)
http://serjo96.github.io/matrix/

Answer (score 1):

Объявление функции необязательно делать внутри другой функции и чтобы функция `addElement()` сработать ещё можно вызвать в нужном месте.

Переменную в функцию можно передать через параметры функции, которые можно задать в объявлении функции. В вашем случае получается такой код:

```
function check_matrix () {
  var needRows = $('.matrix_a').find('tr').length;
  var needCols = $('.matrix_b').find('tr:first td').length;

  var hasRows = $('.matrix_c').find('tr').length;
  var hasCols = $('.matrix_c').find('tr:first td').length;

  var message = "Info:\n";

  if (needRows > hasRows) {
    message += "\n- add " + (needRows - hasRows) + " row[s]" ;
  } else if (needRows < hasRows) {
    message += "\n- remove " + (hasRows - needRows) + " row[s]";
  } else {
    message += "\n- rows match";
  }

  message += "\n";

  if (needCols > hasCols) {
    var diff = needCols - hasCols;
    message += "\n- add " + diff + " column[s]";
    addCols(diff); // Добавление нужного количество колонок при нехватке
  } else if (needCols < hasCols) {
    message += "\n- remove " + (hasCols - needCols) + " column[s]";
  } else {
    message += "\n- columns match";
  }

  console.log(message);
}

// Функция для добавления колонок в таблицу
function addCols(colsCount){
  var rows = $('.matrix_c').find('tr');
  var cells = rows.eq(0).find('td').length;
  var count = colsCount;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    count++;
    rows.each(function(index) {
      var rowCount = index + 1;
      $(this).find('td:first').clone().appendTo(this);
    });
  };
}
```

Только учтите, что для добавления недостающих строк у вас функции нет и её нужно делать отдельно, наподобие той, что добавляет колонки.

Comment: Я уже сделал 2 функцию для строк,но опять же не знал как привязать значение)

Comment: я, наверное, тупой :), но смысл действий в функции `addElement` от меня ускользает. Мы согласны, что `$('.matrix_c').find('tr:last');` вернет максимум один элемент?

Comment: @Igor, ага, в оригинале это выглядело по-другому: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524298 Сейчас попытаюсь вернуть обратно к работоспособному коду

Comment: @Drop, вы как-то странно переделали мою функцию, теперь она не работает как надо, то есть не добавляет по ячейке во все строки. Объясните что делает эта строка: `$(this).clone().appendTo('.matrix_c')`  зачем вам нужно использовать именно `clone()`?

Comment: @MasterAlex она копирует последнюю строчку в matrix_c а затем вставляет ее туда же. У меня весь функционал добавления строк и столбцов стоит на colne, как мне сказали разницы особой по добавлению элемента нет. Ну и если не понравиться человеку то скажут переделать на вставку элементов)

Comment: Кстати по идее можно же из функции копирования сделать условие?Что бы сократить код. Мне придется писать еще 2 функции на удаление строк и столбцов.

Comment: @Igor я сделал по аналогии копирование, думал что так он найдет нужный элемент и через переменную которая берет необходимое число для копирования.

Comment: Ругается `Unexpected token else` на `else if (needCols < hasCols)` у меня такая ошибка выходила из за вызова функции в if)

Comment: @Drop оберните код между `if (needCols > hasCols)` и `else if (needCols < hasCols)` в фигурные скобки

Comment: @Igor не а, ругается.

Comment: @Drop, для начала предлагаю вам прийти к пониманию того, что происходит у вас в получившемся коде, поможет в этом этот учебник: https://learn.javascript.ru/ и когда разберётесь, то сами поймёте что и как нужно делать дальше. На ваш вопрос по поводу передачи переменной в функцию я ответил, а то что у вас изначально был нерабочий код, это уже другой вопрос и связан он именно с тем, что вы не понимаете, что делаете, а копипаст без понимания приводит к ошибкам. К примеру,  вы взяли мой код по добавлению колонок и превратили его в нерабочий код по добавлению строк, естественно что он не работает.

Comment: @MasterAlex не спорю,но из ошибок рождается вопрос а из вопроса уже идет размышление и понимание. Там на learnjs с синтаксисом не очень много разъяснений,так что приходиться прибегать к очевидным вопросам) Но тут я каюсь, еще не особо вникал в данный код

Comment: @MasterAlex да,и на сайтах с основами не найти объяснений зачем названии функции используют в самой функции или про использования переменной i с добавлением числа через ++ и многое многое)

Comment: @Drop, как же нет, вот статья: `https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#параметры`  это основы языка, если бы вы это читали, то наверняка бы знали как создавать и вызывать функции с параметрами. И зря вы на сайт наговариваете, там есть много примеров к каждому чиху, и даже задания для решения на понимание темы есть.

Comment: @MasterAlex возможно упустил,спасибо почитаю)ну к примеру про циклы гораздо доходчевее объяснено здесь http://www.puzzleweb.ru/javascript/11_loops.php

Comment: @Drop, гораздо доходчивее, чем где? чем тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for ? Странные выводы, по вашей ссылке копипаст обычного текста из старого учебника, нудный и тяжёлый для понимания. Практических рекомендаций какой лучше цикл использовать в реальных ситуациях нет, в общем, я бы эту статью не рекомендовал новичку для освоения циклов, такой материал опасен разрывом мозга.

Comment: @MasterAlex - добавьте, пожалуйста, `{  }` перед `else if (needCols < hasCols)`

Comment: @MasterAlex не буду спорить, каждому свое. Там можно получить понятие о том что такое цикл и как из него выходить . А тут уже более углубленное понимание да еще и с картинками для тех кто в танке)

Comment: @Igor, добавил и заодно поправил добавление колонок, в таком виде оно уже должно добавлять колонки через функцию